# set tint color of an UIBarButtonItem for a specific view controller ios6

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

Called from application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
+(void)styleNavbar {
  [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:45/255.0 green:48/255.0 blue:53/255.0 alpha:1]];
  [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(0,1.0)]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:22/255.0 green:24/255.0 blue:26/255.0 alpha:1]];
}
```

I am now trying to use a different color scheme in view controllers from one of my storyboards.

I have been able to set tints for navigation bar and ordinary buttons.

In my -viewDidLoad:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[MyColorScheme sharedInstance].lightBlueColor];
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTintColor:[MyColorScheme sharedInstance].lightBlueColor];
```

But I am struggling with doing the same thing to the back button which continues to use the global colorscheme unless I comment the +styleNavbar lines out. I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem.backBarButtonItem setTintColor:[MyColorScheme sharedInstance].lightBlueColor];
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTintColor:[MyColorScheme sharedInstance].lightBlueColor];
[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTintColor:[MyColorScheme sharedInstance].lightBlueColor];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MySpecificViewController class], nil] setTintColor:[MyColorScheme sharedInstance].lightBlueColor];
```

Running all of the above lines doesn't appear to override the tint for the back button even though I can style other navbar elements from the same method. Is it possible to style the back button after setting its color with the application wide appearance proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` to override the global setting for your specific view controller's Toolbar/Navigationbar. You'll need to create a subclass for the Navigationbar/Toolbar you want tinted differently.
[The Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) gives examples how this is done.

Comment: I have tried (in the last line of the posted code): [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MySpecificViewController class], nil] setTintColor:[MyColorScheme sharedInstance].lightBlueColor];
The line (among other attempts) does nothing, hence this question. I apologize for not making it more clear but the pasted code is 9 lines in total so it shouldn't be that hard to spot.

Comment: Sorry, it's because the BarButtonItem isn't actually contained in your ViewController, but inside a Toolbar/NavigationBar. You'll have to create a subclass of UINavigationBar/UIToolbar and use that for the custom styling.

Comment: An ingenious way! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your bar button's title text attributes on `viewWillAppear` like this:

```
[self.rightBarButton setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor orangeColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And if you want to set the old text attributes when you leave this view controller, you can re-update it on `viewWillDisappear`.

Answer (score -1):

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:251.0/255.0 green:59.0/255.0 blue:29.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];

Comment: I understand this will override the tint of the navigation bar throughout the whole application? Not sure if this is in any way relevant to my problem.